# Is there any way for NFS server to know when the file is completely transferred by client?

Tags: linux, nfs, fuse

I am sending some files to a fuse-mounted file system through NFS and CIFS shares.

The intention is, once the file is fully copied, we do some processing on the file, like checksum generation, archival, encryption etc.

The issue in case of NFS i can see is, there are multiple file opens, transfer chunks and releases, and then open again and a release invoked by the NFS daemon and it continues so there is no way to really know that when is the last release.

Is there any way for the NFS server to know that when the NFS client has really closed the connection, and no more transfers possible?

P.S:

When i talk open, i am referring to the fuse callback [struct fuse_operations::open( )](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html) which is initiated by the NFS daemon for a file open

P.S: For a new file creation it follows the callback sequence create, open, and finally release

Answer (score 0):

Check the *NFS_Unstable* entry for */proc/meminfo* and when its value is zero, all the pending NFS data have been accepted by the filer.